# How to make "NO ACTION" detector on frontend?

Tags: javascript, jquery, session, cookies, frontend

When you enter the [codecademy](http://codecademy.com) and doing nothing for a certain amount of time,
you will see the messages saying "Are you still there?".

I want to make this function on my web page, too.
Well, first thought for this idea, 
using cookies or sessions is going to be the best way? 
Or Any good idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe not the most elegant solution, but I think it achieves what you are looking for.

```
$(function() {
  var interval;
  var startTime = new Date();
  var checkTime = function () {
    var endTime = new Date();
    var elapsed = endTime - startTime;
    var seconds = Math.round(elapsed / 1000);
    var minutes = Math.round(seconds / 60);
    console.log("seconds since mouse move: " + seconds);
    if (seconds >= 5) {
      console.log("Are you still there?");
      clearInterval(interval);
    } 
  };
  interval = setInterval(checkTime, 1000);

  $(document).on('mousemove', function(e) {
    console.log('mouse moved');
    startTime = new Date();
    clearInterval(interval);
    interval = setInterval(checkTime, 1000);
   });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/rqaprga9/1/